# Sliding time specific images with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to slide 36 time specific images throughout the day. How can I do this? 
I tried many times, but it's not working.

**I built the code below -**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var i = 0;
function decimalaxis()
{

    var d = new Date();
    var h = d.getUTCHours();
    var m = d.getUTCMinutes();
    var s = d.getUTCSeconds();

    var i = document.getElementById("Num");
    i.innerHTML = Math.floor(1.5*h + 0.025*m + 0.0004166667*s);
    return i;

function slider(){
    var image = document.getElementById("slide");
image[] = new img[35];
String fileLocation = new String();
for (int i = 0; i < 35; i++)
    {
    fileLocation = "img" + i + ".jpg";
        image[i] = new img('img');
    document.write("<img src="img" + i + ".jpg" id="slide");
    }
}
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with your code is that you are not combining the image string properly.

Try this:

```
document.write("<img src='img" + i + ".jpg' id='slide'/>");
```

Instead of this:

```
document.write("<img src="img" + i + ".jpg" id="slide");
```

A different method would be to put this in the slider function

```
function slider(){
    var image = document.getElementById("slide");
    var imageList = new Array(35);
    for (int i = 0; i < imageList.length; i++)
    {
        //create a new image element
        var currentImage = document.createElement("img");
        currentImage.src = "img" + i + ".jpg";
        currentImage.id = "slide";

        //add the current image to the image list
        imageList.push(currentImage);

        //append to image element
        image.appendChild(currentImage);
    }

}
```